# AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'db_parameters'

Tags: python-3.x, django

После мерджа веток запускаю тесты и на всех приложениях получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\191.7141.48\helpers\pycharm\django_test_manage.py", line 168, in <module>
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\191.7141.48\helpers\pycharm\django_test_manage.py", line 142, in execute
    _create_command().run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\test.py", line 26, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\191.7141.48\helpers\pycharm\django_test_manage.py", line 104, in handle
    failures = TestRunner(test_labels, **options)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\191.7141.48\helpers\pycharm\django_test_runner.py", line 255, in run_tests
    extra_tests=extra_tests, **options)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\191.7141.48\helpers\pycharm\django_test_runner.py", line 156, in run_tests
    return super(DjangoTeamcityTestRunner, self).run_tests(test_labels, extra_tests, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 604, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\runner.py", line 551, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 174, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\creation.py", line 68, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 148, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\evgeny\PycharmProjects\goslim\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 493, in alter_field
    old_db_params = old_field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'db_parameters'
```

Перед этим смерджил миграции командой `python manage.py makemigrations --merge`

Не подскажете в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Нужен полный текст ошибки, без пропуска.

Comment: обновил текст ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил откатив код назад и убрав конфликты из миграций